# How does HTTP header "cache-control: s-maxage=31536000, stale-while-revalidate" work?

Tags: http, next.js, cdn, cache-control, s-maxage

I'm using NextJS on my project. For every page requests it adds 's-maxage=31536000, stale-while-revalidate' cache-control rules in response. How are these 2 rules supposed to work together?

Answer (score 4):

`s-maxage` and `stale-while-revalidate` are part of the `cache-control` [HTTP header standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) that instruct caching of web objects.

As your question alludes, they are allowed to be comma separated to achieve your desired [caching strategy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#examples).

```
Cache-Control: s-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate=60
```

The first value (`s-maxage`) is how long the object should be cached in seconds. It also "overrides `max-age` or the `Expires` header, but only for shared caches (e.g., proxies) and is ignored by private caches" - see [HTTP expiration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#expiration)

The second value (`stale-while-revalidate`), [if supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#browser_compatibility), is how long after the `s-maxage` expiration the object can be cached for until it needs to be requested from your site again.

---

#### Example

- Initial request - content is cached with the above `cache-control` directives
- Request between 1-60 seconds after the initial request - Displays the cached content - revalidates in the background
- Request 60 or more seconds after the initial request - Cause the browser to request a new version of the content to serve.

---

Here is how to set [caching headers in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching).

Here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697463/15304814) I made that highlights ISR process in Next.js.

Comment: Note that `s-maxage` does *not* mean the same as `maxage` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39992837/733345); and the relevant spec would be 'HTTP', rather than 'HTML'.

Comment: Good catch Joe!  Late night typo.  I didn't explain how s-maxage overrides maxage for shared caches bc it's directly under max-age in the spec.  But it's doesn't hurt to add it here for the tl;dr;

Comment: 's-maxage=31536000, stale-while-revalidate' header is set by NextJS (SSG) out of the box for html requests. In your explanation you are saying that s-maxage header is for proxies only. Why do we need to cache html files on proxies? Why stale-while-revalidate doesn't have a value?

Comment: I didn't say it was only for proxies - that is the HTTP spec's explanation (see the spec I linked).  Stale-while-revalidate doesn't have a value bc it's not being used.  You'd cache a proxy so you don't have to hit your web servers on every request, it's standard to cache at the proxy level. https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/cdn-caching/

Comment: So for 's-maxage=31536000, stale-while-revalidate' does this mean stale-while-revalidate will be always ignored (because it doesn't have a value) and the html file requested will be cached on proxy (CDN) for 1 year?

Comment: If you are using a server that respects the s-maxage header, it will request (not guaranteed) to be cached for 1 year in your case. The proxy server can also set it's own cache eviction rules (common example aws cloudfront cache invalidation).    Yes, stale-while-revalidate is essentially off.

Comment: In this example, isn't `stale-while-revalidate` a client-side header used alongside the server-side `s-maxage`?  Does Next.js support server-side stale-while-revalidate in an API route via a header?